# does a (unix domain) socket in an nfs-exported fs "magically" work across hosts?

Tags: nfs

This question applies to the nfsv4 implementation that ships with debian.

If two hosts have the nfs share mounted, and a socket exists in the fs, can processes on the two hosts talk to each other through this socket?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does a Unix domain socket in an NFS-exported fs "magically" work across hosts?

No - Unix domain sockets are within that kernel / namespace only, and don't operate across hosts.

```
attie@perdy:~/nfs_dir $ nc -lU test.sock
```

```
attie@patch:~/nfs_dir $ nc -U test.sock
nc: unix connect failed: Connection refused
```

Comment: thanks.  All is clear (despite mild disappointment)